# Independent operation of watchOS app when sharing app with iOS app

Tags: ios, core-data, watchos-2, watchconnectivity

My iOS app uses CoreData as its data store and I have added a watchOS app to accompany it. Currently the workflow between the iOS and watchOS apps is as follows:

1. The watchOS app exposes a menu representing a subset of functions available in the iOS app
2. Choosing one of these options sends a message to the iOS app telling it which option was selected
3. The iOS app responds by packaging up any data needed by the watch for that particular function into a dictionary and sending this back to the watch in the reply handler
4. The watchOS app presents an interface to the user allowing them to change the values in the data
5. Each change sends a message to the iOS app which updates the core data store with the new values

This is working fine but clearly requires the phone to be connected to the watch throughout the use of the app for it to work. I'm wondering whether a model like the following would be possible:

1. As above
2. As above
3. As above
   3a. The watch stores the data locally
4. As above
5. Each change updates the watch app's local copy of the data
6. The user can later check the data back in to the iOS app at which point it is merged into the core data database

I can guarantee that conflicts would not be an issue as the user would never be able to modify data which had already been created on the phone (it is not a requirement of the app to be able to do so).

So my question is, would the latter case allow the watchOS app to operate independently of the iOS app with the exception of transferring data, and is this a preferable method to the way I am handing this currently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*It's simpler for your watch app to be dependent on the phone. It's more complex for it to operate independently of the phone. Only you can 
answer whether the added complexity to support true independence is worth it, since you're the person who has to implement, support, and maintain any additional code needed.*

**Do the changes make the watch app independent?**

No, they don't let the watch app operate independently, since the watch still must request/receive data from the phone during steps 2 and 3.

For the watch app to be completely independent while away from the phone, it would have to query a local copy of the data which the phone updated as needed, instead of requiring the phone to send any remote data that the watch needs.

**Is the change preferable?**

Not as it stands. Your proposed change to defer updating the phone (even though it's still reachable) may require much unnecessary code related to locally storing data for the present, and merging updates back to the phone in the future.

Also, while you promise there presently is no merge conflict to deal with, there's no guarantee that any revisions you make to your app in the future won't introduce the possibility for conflicts to occur.

If you choose to establish two persistent stores, it would make your app less fragile to implement a merge policy **now**, to avoid your updates from completely failing to save, should a future conflict occur.

**The real question...**

Is the freedom to operate away from the phone (for hours) worth showing stale (or possibly misleading) data to the user?

Unless you also provide an indication showing when the data was refreshed by the phone, the user may assume that the displayed information is current and accurate, even though it may be hours old.

This adds more complexity to the watch app either in the user-facing UI or behind the scenes to handle stale data.

For your consideration, Apple Watch's Weather app simply shows no data at all when it can't obtain the current weather data from the phone (since users would want to know the **current** temperature and chance of precipitation).

Comment: Very interesting, response, thank you. To clarify, this is a gym workout logging app. The user creates workout routines on the iOS app and can then create workout instances to log weights, distances etc. In this case I do think it beneficial to be able to upload a workout to the watch, leave the phone in the locker, do your workout, then push the completed workout back to the phone. In the end it was rather trivial to implement the local storage since the routine structure was already packaged up into a dictionary. I have now got to the point where changes to the routine measurements are...

Comment: ... made on the local copy of the data and saved to disk for persistence (just by archiving the dictionary and saving it). Since a routine will only ever exist on the watch OR the phone (never both), there is no issue with 'stale' data as you put it, and I do think that in this instance it is preferable not to have to rely on the phone if you are working out with the watch app. However, your answer is extremely informative for others in similar predicaments so I will accept as the correct answer since the information you provided has definitely given me food for thought!

Comment: Are you doing any of this in conjunction with HealthKit?  It already handles keeping the phone and watch's HealthKit stores in sync and you could query its store instead of keeping your data in your own store. I realize that `HKWorkout` might not support a specific type of workout that you want to do yet, but it is designed to handle the *exact* scenario that you described.

Comment: No, I'm not using HealthKit. I want to maintain iPad compatibility, and HKWorkout is not suitable in this particular case. Thank you for the suggestion though!